# How to re-enable Visual Studio automatic step-over notification?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2019

While debugging in Visual Studio 2019, I received the following message:

> Your step-into request resulted in an automatic step-over of a property or operator.
>   This behavior can be overridden in the context menu for the line being executed by choosing 'Step Into Specific' or by unchecking the option 'Step over properties and operators'.
>   Do you want continue being notified when an automatic step-over happens?

I answered "No" to the dialog, but now I've changed my mind. How do I re-enable this notification?

Comment: I can't confirm since I've not disabled any, but it sounds like it might be Tools > Options > Environment > Notifications.

Comment: Thanks @John_ReinstateMonica, but in Visual Studio 2019 there is no "Notifications" section under Tools > Options > Environment.

Comment: Hi, please try to reset VS option settings and project settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but now I've changed my mind. How do I re-enable this notification?

l think you could meet this message by resetting settings of VS and project.

You can try these steps:

**1)** First, reset VS settings by `Tools-->Import and Export settings...-->Reset all settings`.

**2)** Then, delete the **.vs** hidden folder under the solution path which stores project settings, options.

"WARNING: Use this at your own risk. It WILL reset your settings and do things like reset your Toolbox thus getting rid of any custom tabs, code pieces, etc.. you have put in there."

Comment: if I understand correctly, this will reset all settings, not just the setting in question. "WARNING:  Use this at your own risk.  It WILL reset your settings and do things like reset your Toolbox thus getting rid of any custom tabs, code pieces, etc.. you have put in there." Is this correct?

Comment: In VS2019, there is no options to restore the previous notification. So you should store the settings. l suggest you could try step 2 first which stores related project settings. If not, you should try step one. And l suggest you could make a backup before restoring your settings. You will see the backup operation on the next step of Resetting settings. You can load the previous backup by (`Tools-->Options-->Environment-->Import and Export settings`).